# Is there a solution to print and plot the test code result of an array or a random input in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am new in this field of matlab.

The situation is when I enter only one input variable, The program run with no error. But when I use random or an array , the program works just when All the values of the array of Per are greater or less than D, except that my program does not display results in the Command window.

Whatever Per greater or less than D I have all the message of the current situation.
I want also to know how I can print also the results Per, D, S and Psc in the same graph in function of time (hour) whatever the max value or size of the randome / array variables.

Thanks for your help.

```
clear all
clc
%t=1:24;
Ppv=2*rand(1,5); %[10 0 40 50 5 1 2 3 1 1 1 1];  
Pwt=rand(1,5); %[10 0 40 5 5 1 2 3 3 4 55 5];  

LPac=rand(1,5); %[10 20 40 50 5 1 2 3 5 6 7 9]; 
LSac=rand(1,5); %[1 2 40 5 51 2 3 33 9 0 3 2];

LPdc=rand(1,5); %[1 20 4 50 51 24 3 3 4 6 7 8];
LSdc=rand(1,5); %[10 0 4 0 51 2 324 3 8 5 3 2];


 for i=1:1:1
    Dac=LPac+LSac; 
   Ddc=LPdc+LSdc; 
   Per=Ppv+Pwt; 
    D=Dac+Ddc;   
   Lp=LPac+LPdc; 
    Ls=LSac+LSdc; 

        if Per>D 
   if   Sac)>0  && Sdc>0 
        fprintf(' S de %d .\n',S)
       fprintf(' Sac de %d .\n',Sac) 
       fprintf(' Sdc de %d .\n',Sdc)
       fprintf(' St de %d .\n',St)
   end

if  Ppv>Ddc &  Pwt<=Dac
   SDC=Sdc-abs(Sac);
   SAC=0;
   fprintf(' S de %d .\n',S)
  fprintf(' DC Sdc de %d .\n',SDC)
  printf('  St de %d .\n',St)
       elseif   any(Sac )>0 & any(Sdc)<=0
  SAC=Sac-abs(Sdc);
  SDC=0;
  fprintf(' S de %d .\n',S)
  fprintf(' Sac de %d .\n',SAC)
  fprintf('  St de %d .\n',St)
end

if Per < D

Lp=LPac+LPdc; 
Ls=LSac+LSdc; 
DDdc=Ppv-LPdc;
Ddeldc=LSdc-abs(DDdc); 
DDac=Pwt-LPac;
Ddelac=LSac-abs(DDac); 
DD=DDac+DDdc; 
Ddel=Ddeldc+Ddelac ; 

  if Per>=Lp
          fprintf(' Ddel de %d .\n',Ddel)
              if Ppv>=LPdc || Pwt>=LPac

          fprintf(' Ddeldc de %d .\n',Ddeldc)
          fprintf('Ddelac de %d .\n',Ddelac)
              end

  else
              Dextdc=Ppv-LPdc; 
              Dextac=Pwt-LPac;   
              Dext=Dextdc+Dextac; 
              Psc=abs(Dext); 

                    if Ppv<LPdc && Pwt>LPac
               Pscac=0;
               Pscdc=abs(Dextdc+Dextac);
                elseif Ppv>LPdc && Pwt<LPac
               Pscac=abs(Dextac+Dextdc);
               Pscdc=0;
                    else Ppv<LPdc && Pwt<LPac

              Pscac=abs(Dextac);
              Pscdc=abs(Dextdc);
                    end  
            fprintf('Ddel %d .\n',Ls) 
            fprintf('Pscdc %d .\n',Pscdc)
            fprintf('Pscac %d .\n',Pscac) 
            fprintf('Psc %d . \n',Psc)

    end 
    end

      if Per==D
           disp(" tout est bien ")
      end

      end
```

Comment: I think you have got your `if`/`end` statements in the wrong places. If you indent the code (`ctrl`+`i` in the editor window in Matlab) you will see that the `if Per < D` is inside the `if Per>D` loop, maybe it should be an `elseif Per < D`?

Comment: Hello, thank  you for your comment I correct it, but still, the code work perfectly just for one simple input  but for  r multiple input still not working ( if i use rand(x,y) or a simple array or vector.

Comment: i forget to add  : _italic_ **bold** `  
S=Per-D  ; 
St=Per-LPac-LPdc;
Sac=Pwt-Dac;
Sdc=Ppv-Ddc;` after the Ls variable in the loop for ad before _italic_ **bold** `if Per>D`

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little trouble understanding the first part of your question, but plotting several variables on the same figure is easy:

```
figure; hold on
plot(Per); plot(D); plot(S); plot(Psc);
hold off
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, can you please also help me  for the problem of the input ? when its a simple input it works when i use rand or an array it does not work .